# Best Web Analytics Tool for Salesforce?

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Recently, the business has been interested in web analysis within our lightning application to track how often certain type of users are clicking certain links within the app. For example:

- How often are they scheduling a task?
- How often are they looking at their dashboards and reports

  - Which ones specifically?

In general, we want to know clicking patterns and frequencies along with tracking how long it takes to do these things. Does Salesforce itself have something that could do this for us, or would we have to go out and find a third party tool and integrate? If the latter, do you have any experience or recommendations? I have heard of tools such as SiteCatalyst and Tealeaf that handle this need, but does anyone have experience integrating these with Salesforce? I cannot find much information on the integration process and the Salesforce descriptions of their own analytic products are very vague.

Comment: I suggest you take a look on the App Exchange. There are ISV's who've already created solutions of the type you're asking about that include Google Analytics and more, but I can't recommend anything in particular.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a part of the standard platform so you'll need either Wave, as Geoff mentions, or a third party solution.

Dashcord can be found on the AppExchange and is a completely native marketing automation tool for Salesforce; as part of it's email tracking capabilities you can create trackable links which feed into scoring etc., and you can indeed use these links on websites to track usage. I suspect you could leverage these within your app, but it honestly depends on how those links are working. If they're just triggering JS events and client-side navigation then perhaps your best bet is to simply create your own logging service and track links yourself and page views yourself with a simple apex service and an object to record data.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, ask your Acct Exec to show you a demo of Event Monitoring (Wave for IT).

Comment: Can you expand on this at all to list some of the capabilities or something?

Comment: Here's the best list:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_app_admin_wave_dashboards.htm&type=0